# Business with French/Israeli Nationalists

Tags: halal-haram, business, bani-israel

I am a freelancer and working with people from all over the world is common for me. But whenever I receive an offer from a client residing in **Israel/France**, I find myself standing in a complete confusion whether to work with them or not. Unfortunately I could not find a clear cut answer for this so posting it here now with high hopes.

So the thing is I am aware I should not do the work with anybody if it involves anything anti-islamic like Betting, Winery etc but in most of the cases, work involved is all good but then I think Israel is an illegal oppressive state and they would get taxes from that client I would work with. So indirectly some of that money is gonna get used against Muslims. Same is the case with France, they promote Islamophobia at a state level and do other blasphemic contests as well. So a French person's tax is gonna get used by their Govt in in that regard too. So wouldn't it be Haram to get involved with such people and work?

I understand somebody may think that this logic makes working Haram with US citizens as well because they launch anti-muslim activities too but the thing (I think) is US does not do it openly. Those are their secret missions or what so ever. But France and Israel do it openly and back such anti-islamic activities publicly.

Share your valuable thoughts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaam al-Bukhaaree (d. 256H, rahimahullaah), the author of the famous work commonly known as “Saheeh al-Bukhaaree”. He states in his chapter heading:

**“Chapter: Buying and Selling with the Mushrikeen (the Pagans) and with the Enemies of War.”**

So after bringing this chapter heading showing the permissibility of buying and selling, he states:

> Abdur-Rahmaan b. Abee Bakr (radiyallaahu ‘anhumaa) said: We were with
> the Prophet (ﷺ) when a tall pagan with long
> matted unkempt hair came driving his sheep. The Prophet (salallaahu
> ‘alaihi wassallam) asked him:
>
> “Are those sheep for sale or for gifts?” The pagan replied: “They are
> for sale.” So the Prophet (salallaahu ‘alaihi wassallam) bought one
> sheep from him. (Bukhaaree no. 2216)

However if the ruler issues such a command forbidding purchase of products or to boycott certain goods from certain countries, then it is obligatory to obey him in that. As for individuals calling for these boycotts and, then that is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Buying from Israel is Haram. Why?

If you buy anything From Israel or help them, they get more tax. The more they get tax, the more bomb would be produced with that. And by giving them money, people are helping them commit genocide. So is helping Israel to kill innocent children and women Halal? No.

Now, if you want to mention the hadith from Bukhari where Prophet didn't boycott, read this:
Boycotting of then and boycotting of now aren't same. Pagans didn't made bombs with tax money then, but you know what Israel can do with tax. So don't enable them more to murder.

And to talk about France, avoid them too. Because the money earnt using your work/things or your money might be used for Islamophobic purposes.